# @JsonProperty being ignored when sending in @Body of a @POST request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, retrofit

The @JsonProperty annotation seems to not be working correctly for me when I try sending an object in the @Body of a @Post request (using retrofit). What is stumping me is when I put a breakpoint in my code just before I execute the post request, the debugger tells me that the @JsonProperty has worked and shows the object to have the name I assigned to it using @JsonProperty.

eg: 
Declaration: `@JsonProperty("interval_step") private long intervalStep;`

Yet when this is sent with retrofit (as a @Post request), the @JsonProperty annotation is ignored.

Any insight on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you try using JsonProperty to the getter function of that variable

Comment: I've tried it on the getter and the setter and still the same issue occurs

Comment: I have tried and it is working. can you check import
I am using com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty

Comment: Yes thats the same library I am using. I believe the issue has something to do with sending the object in the @Body of a Post request - some how its taking the Raw Json and ignoring the annotation?